# Filtering OpenInfraMap vector tiles by layer name in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, vector-tiles

When I load the `OpenInfraMap` vector tile service in QGIS 3.28.1 ([https://openinframap.org/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://openinframap.org/tiles/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)), how can I filter the data by layer name?

OpenInfraMap uses different layers as we can see in the [TileJSON](https://openinframap.org/map.json) file.

Unfortunately, the [Vector Tile Reader](https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin) plugin doesn't work anymore with OpenInfraMap.
I get the following error: `The field 'vector_layers' is required but not found. This is invalid TileJSON`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees!
The answer was so near. We can filter the layer directly in the layer properties symbology dialog:
[image]